# jsdom 9.1+ does not set document.activeElement when focusing a node

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom, enzyme

I'm using jsdom with enzyme+mocha+chai to test the behavior of a React component. The component has a method to focus a DOM node (using the usual `node.focus()`) and I want to test the node is actually focused when it's called.

To know which node is focused, I compare `document.activeElement` to the node I expect to be focused.

However, after upgrading to jsdom 9.1+, `document.activeElement` seems always be `HTMLBodyElement`, even after calling the node's `focus()` method.

With jsdom 9.0 the tests run fine.

I read jsdom 9.1+ [contains some changes](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/Changelog.md#910) related to the focus event, yet I couldn't understand how make `document.activeElement` behave as expected. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be that you are missing a `tabindex` attribute on the element that you are trying to focus? It must be set to a valid integer for jsdom to interpret it as focusable.

You can see this in the [jsdom source code](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/commit/1805283257cc20c933ecb723cb9980235f592de6#diff-cc2373d602988c88cacb079ed550e374R21).

Answer (score 2):

To extend @Epeli's answer:

The element to be focussed must indeed be added to the DOM tree before document.activeElement can be set to it.

If you are mounting a component and want to check if something inside of that component got focussed, try to add the following inside your test:

```
test(() => {
    const wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent />)
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper.find('#FocusElement').getDOMNode())
    // the rest of your test...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason it might not work is that the element has not been added to the DOM tree.

```js
const input = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(input);

input.focus();
console.log(document.activeElement === input)
```